# Which of “Will you just go?” or “Can you just go?” works better?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs, politeness, register

One of my stu­dents barged into my class­room one day and was
get­ting on my nerves be­cause I needed to clean up the mess he had
him­self made ear­lier, so I wanted to ask him to leave me alone
and go away.

Which of these two pos­si­ble ways of ask­ing him to leave would
be more nat­u­ral for me to use in this sit­u­a­tion?  Do they mean 
the same thing? Is one bet­ter?

> 1. **Will** you just go?
> 2. **Can** you just go?

If both are gram­mat­i­cal con­struc­tions that a na­tive speaker would
rou­tinely use, then which if ei­ther is pre­ferred for this
par­tic­u­lar cir­cum­stance and why? Is this the nor­mal way to 
ex­press what I want to say, and if not, then what would be bet­ter?

Comment: Both are grammatical, it's a matter of personal taste which one you prefer to use. I might tell someone "get outta here"  if I was feeling particularly annoyed and wasn't afraid of the possible consequences that my rudeness might incur.

Comment: An interesting aspect about this question is that both modals are being used in a special way:  this is **ɴᴏᴛ** the *will* used to describe future events. Instead, here it’s actually the *will* that means “wants to” or “would like to”. In the Greek technobabble of formal linguistics, this is thus the so-called [deontic mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_modality), a more piquant flavor of portraying **the world as we would *ʜᴀᴠᴇ* it be,** not the simpler “expected” one. It covers “permissions and volitions”—so things like commands, wants, wishes, desires, promises, or even threats.

Answer (score -2):

"Will you leave?" leaves the choice of leaving to the student, as it is asking if student would leave.

"Can you leave?" is asking if the student has the ability to leave.

In terms of actual meaning, there is a slight difference between the two phrases, but there isn't one that is really better than the other. In both of the  phrases, the context and tone matter more than the words being used. So, both will get your message across.

Another way of conveying your message could also be "Please leave." 
Instead of asking the student, you could just tell the student what you want him to do. Though, this may come off harsher than either of the questions you listed above.